# Report Builder 1.0 and MandatoryFilter

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

We're using ReportBuilder 1.0 (2005) for now.

I'm not understanding the way that the MandatoryFilter setting is working.  It doesn't consistently prompt for a filter, only when certain fields are included in the report and only when selected in a certain way.

For example, if I double click on an entity it will add all of the non computed fields to the report.  This prompts for a filter.

Adding these same fields by clicking the fields does not prompt for the filter.

This seems inconsistent.

Also, double-clicking the entity yields fields that are all under one 'tab' - which is labeled with the table name.   If I single click the fields, they each have a tab titled with the field name.  Does this have some significance?

I've tried asking at the MS forums, but no replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://blogs.msdn.com/bobmeyers/archive/2006/12/20/getting-grouping-right-in-report-builder.aspx

Thanks to Aaron Meyers at MSFT for the help!